# How to grab the ID of a DIV tag referenced by the Class ID instead

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab the ID of a DIV class referenced by its Class name using JQuery, but failed to do it.

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
alert($(this).id);
}

<DIV id="myTest1" class="myClass">
Helloworld I am new to JQuery 1
</DIV>

   <DIV id="myTest2" class="myClass">
    Helloworld I am new to JQuery 2
    </DIV>
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

should do the trick!!

jim

Comment: Thank you Jim for your quick help.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    alert(this.id);
}
```

or

```
$(".myClass").click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
}
```

Comment: Many thanks to Am for your help. But I have to select Jim since he came first for this question.